# Value of type 'DateComponents' has no member 'DateComponentsFormatter'

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to use the DateComponentFormatter to remove the details in the NSDateComponent (see screenshot) but it throws me 3 errors:

1. Cannot convert return expression of type '()' to return type 'DateComponents'
2. Reference to member 'year' cannot be resolved without a contextual type
3. Value of type 'DateComponents' has no member 'DateComponentsFormatter'

I tried setting a `lazy var formatter = DateComponentsFormatter` like in the tutorials, but it more or less throw the same error. It also doesn't work attaching the formatter to the `remainder`  but it throws the mutatable error.

Big thanks in advance!

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var birthDay: Date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(year: -30), to: Date()) ?? Date()
    lazy var remainder = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(year: 73), to: birthDay)
    lazy var remainderComp = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year], from: now, to: remainder!)
    
    let now = Date()

    var body: some View {
                VStack {
                    NavigationView {
                        VStack {
                            Text("Your birthday...?")
                                .font(.title)
                            DatePicker("", selection: $birthDay, in:...Date(), displayedComponents: .date)
                                .datePickerStyle(.compact)
                                .labelsHidden()
                            Text("""
                                 The world's average life expectancy in 2022 is
                                 73 years
                                 """)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                            Text("You still have: ")
                            Text("\(remainderCompValue()) years on earth")
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                }
    }
    
    func remainderCompValue() -> DateComponents {
        var mutatableSelf = self
        return mutatableSelf.remainderComp.DateComponentsFormatter().allowedUnits = [.year]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a `DateComponentsFormatter`, there are a few issues:

1. The following line does not makes sense:

   ```swift
   mutatableSelf.remainderComp.DateComponentsFormatter().allowedUnits = [.year]
   ```

   You should create a `DateComponentsFormatter` property and set its `allowedUnits` (and presumably its `unitStyle`). E.g.:

   ```swift
   let formatter: DateComponentsFormatter = {
       let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
       formatter.allowedUnits = [.year]
       formatter.unitsStyle = .full
       return formatter
   }()
   ```
2. The issue in the screen snapshot is that you are not using the `DateComponentsFormatter` that you should have created in the prior step. So, first, I would retire `remainder`, `remainderComp`, and `now` and just have a function to prepare the “number of years left” string:

   ```swift
   func remainingYearsString(for date: Date) -> String? {
       guard let expectancyEndOfLife = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .year, value: 73, to: date) else {
           return nil
       }

       return formatter.string(from: .now, to: expectancyEndOfLife)
   }
   ```

   Note that that the `DateComponents` object is now redundant and no longer needed.

   Anyway, I would then have the `View` use that function:

   ```swift
   var body: some View {
       VStack {
           NavigationView {
               VStack {
                   Text("Your birthday...?")
                       .font(.title)
                   DatePicker("", selection: $birthDay, in:...Date(), displayedComponents: .date)
                       .datePickerStyle(.compact)
                       .labelsHidden()
                   Text("""
                        The world's average life expectancy in 2022 is
                        73 years
                        """
                   ).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                   Text("You still have: ")
                   Text("\(remainingYearsString(for: birthDay) ?? "unknown time") on earth")
                   Spacer()
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Note that the date components formatter will include the “years” string, so you will notice that I have removed the redundant “years” in the `Text(...)` string.

Comment: FWIW, you might also consider looking at `formatter.includesTimeRemainingPhrase = true` …